# Failing to understand some basic idea behind differentiation

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, chain-rule, leibniz-integral-rule

I just discovered I must have some big holes in my knowledge of basic calculus, and this is scary honestly.

I have to compute some derivatives of the solution of a dynamical system:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\text d y(t)}{\text dt} = f(t,y(t)),\quad y(t_0) = y_0,\quad t_0\leq t\leq T.
\end{equation*}

Say that I have to compute derivatives with respect to $t$. Clearly, $\dfrac{\text d y(t)}{\text dt}$ is given.

1. I want to compute $\dfrac{\text d y(t)}{\text du}$ with $u<t$.
   I write:
   \begin{equation*}
   y(t) = y(u) +\int_u^t f(\tau,y(\tau))\text d \tau\therefore\dfrac{\text d y(t)}{\text du}=\dfrac{\text d y(u)}{\text du}+\dfrac{\text d}{\text du}\int_u^t f(\tau,y(\tau))\text d \tau=f(u,y(u))+?
   \end{equation*}
   The question mark stays for the fact that I have some uncertainties in how to compute the derivative of the integral by Leibniz rule. I will not report here all my doubts, I could fill pages.
2. I assume $\dfrac{\text d y(t)}{\text du}=0$ with $u>t$ for physical reasons (how can future influence past?), but is it *actually* true? If I unwind all the computation I will get by chain rule some terms like $\dfrac{\text d t}{\text du}$. Intuitively, it should be zero, but since $\dfrac{\text d t}{\text du}=\left(\dfrac{\text d u}{\text dt}\right)^{-1}$, then I would set it to 1.
3. the specific case $\dfrac{\text d y(t)}{\text d t_0}$ is the funniest. I get different results when computing it as
   \begin{equation*}
   \dfrac{\text d y(t)}{\text d t_0} = \dfrac{\text d}{\text d t_0}\left(y_0+\int_{t_0}^t f(\tau,y(\tau))\text d\tau\right) = -f(t_0,y_0)
   \end{equation*}
   or
   \begin{equation*}
   \dfrac{\text d y(t)}{\text d t_0} = \dfrac{\text d y(t)}{\text d t}\dfrac{\text d t}{\text d t_0} = f(t,y(t))
   \end{equation*}
4. what about $\dfrac{\text d y(u)}{\text d y(t)}$ with $t<u$, by Leibniz rule? I obtain different results writing $y(u)=y(t)+\int_t^u f(\tau,y(\tau))\text d\tau$ or $y(u)=y_0+\int_0^u f(\tau,y(\tau))\text d\tau$
5. $\dfrac{\text d y(u)}{\text d y(t)}$ with $t>u$ would be 0 for physical reasons, or the inverse of what results in point 4, by algebra of differentials.

How would you solve these doubts? I think I don't get completely the meaning of derivative ..

Comment: I think you mean for both $t$ and $u$ to be independent variables. That is, they can take on any value (within some range) and do not affect each other. In that case, $y(t)$ is independent of $u$ and so $\frac{dy(t)}{du}=0$. Does that help?

Comment: Similarly, $\frac{dy(u)}{dy(t)}$ must be zero because changing the bottom does not affect the top.

Comment: Hi! When you say that $t < u$ or $t > u$, do you mean the values represented by $t$ and $u$, or do you mean for them to be separate variables? If you were interpreting $t$ and $u$ to be just values / numbers, then $\frac{dy}{du}$ can be obtained by substituting $t$ by $u$, like we do for calculating $\frac{d (x^2)}{dx}|_{x=3} = 2x|_{x=3} = 6$.

Comment: @Blitzer, Actually it is not clear to me that $\frac{dy(t)}{du}=0$ if $u<t$. It is true that $u$ is an independent variable, just another time instant, and $y(t)$ does not depend over $u$, but by chain rule I see it not happening. How come? The point is also that to me $\frac{dy(t)}{dy(u)}$ should not be null, because we perturbate the past, and it affects the present via the dynamical system, and so if the derivative of the inverse is the inverse of the derivative, then $\frac{dy(u)}{dy(t)}$ should not as well. What am I missing?

Comment: Further to @Blitzer 's first comment: getting $0$ is exactly what you will get in your calculation labelled 1. The "?" is, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, exactly $-f(u,y(u))$.

Comment: I think that all the confusion is arising from notation. I genuinely have no idea what you mean by $\frac{dy(t)}{du}$. Writing straight $d$'s makes me think you mean to differentiate a function of the variable $u$ wrt $u$. Tell us the function.

Comment: @marco if $u$ is just another time instant, then why is it a variable independent of $t$? It should be a constant (known or unknown does not matter).

Comment: @ancientmathematician the function is the solution to the dynamical system on top, I do not give any specific shape. With $\frac{dy(t)}{d u}$ I mean the sensitivity of $y(t)$ to the value of a previous time instant. It does not make any sense to me as well, but somehow it relates to the dependence from the value of the initial instant $t_0$.

Comment: @P.J. I am honest, I did not understand your last comment .. I am feeling so confused

Comment: A suggestion @marco. Can you formulate what you want to do as a question that might be asked and answered in an exam? For example "given $y(3)=6$ and $y'=2y+7$ find $y(t)$". Perhaps the issue is blurring between notation and logic and it will be easier to discuss with an actual question.

Comment: @Blitzer this is a good idea, I added it to the question.

Comment: Can you go further and explain the "direct computation" you have made at the end?

Comment: @ancientmathematician, meanwhile I changed the expressions correcting some mistakes. The direct computation I did it taking the expression for $y(t)$ containing $y(u)$ and deriving it in $u$. NEWER: I also discovered another mistake, and now $\frac{dy(t)}{du}=0$. At least this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Premise.** As already pointed out in the comments, I believe your confusion stems from a somewhat excessive use of the Leibniz notation for the derivative, rather than a poor understanding of the derivative itself. While the notation $\rm{d}y/\rm{d}t$ is undeniably intuitive and `agile' for some things it is not the most precise notation possible. In particular, it makes a complete mess of the point at which the derivative is being evaluated, making it impossible to distinguish between the independent variable and some fixed point. I suggest we ditch it completely, and instead write $y'(t)$ for the derivative of $y$ at the point $t$. With this in mind, let me address your points one by one

**1)** If $u,t\in[t_0,T]$ and $u<t$, it's certainly true that
$$y(t)=y(u)+\int_u^tf(\tau,y(\tau))\,\rm{d}\tau,$$
but it's not at all clear what $\rm{d}y(t)/\rm{d}u$ even means. If you mean the derivative of $y$ evaluated at the point $u$, i.e. $y'(u)$, then this is just $f(u,y(u))$. Otherwise, you could say $t$ is now fixed and $u$ is your independent variable (this effectively reduces your interval to $[t_0,t]$). Now that the meaning of all symbols has been clarified, you can take a derivative of both sides of your equation: the LHS vanishes because $y(t)$ is now a constant, whereas the RHS reads
$$y'(u) - f(u,y(u)) = y'(u) - y'(u) = 0,$$
i.e. you get the trivial identity $0=0$, as you should.

**2)** Your writing in this point corroborates the idea that to you $\rm{d}y(t)/\rm{d}u$ must stand for $y'(u)$. Let me point out, however, that you have absolutely no reason to assume $y'(u)$ vanishes for $u$ greater than some fixed $t\in[t_0,T]$, *unless* the function $f$ dictates so. For instance if you take $f(t,u(t))=A$ where $A$ is a non-zero constant this is false, but the equation $y'(t)=f(t,y(t))$ makes perfect sense regardless (and it's easily solved). The equation you solve at the end of your post is another example. This is because while *we use* differential equations to describe the time evolution of physical systems, they don't *have to* describe them. Thus if you want a system to be [causal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_system), that's a condition you have to *impose* on the system, otherwise it may well be false.

**3)** Here is where you can see clearly how the Leibniz notation falls short—and, at the same time, how useful it is. The inverse function is defined by the identity
$y(t)=\eta \Longleftrightarrow y^{-1}(\eta)=t,$
then under some [very reasonable circumstances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation) it holds
$$(y^{-1})'(\eta) = \frac{1}{y'(y^{-1}(\eta))} = \frac{1}{y'(t)}.$$
Notice that the LHS is evaluated at a *different point* than the RHS, but if we forget about this and use the Leibniz notation (which does not specify the evaluation point anyway) the identity above reads
$$\frac{\rm{d}y^{-1}(\eta)}{\rm{d}\eta} = \frac{\rm{d}t}{\rm{d}\eta} = \frac{1}{\rm{d}u/\rm{d}t}.$$
Now we may *formally* write this as $$\frac{\rm{d}t}{\rm{d} y}=\left(\frac{\rm{d} y}{\rm{d}t}\right)^{-1},$$
so long as we understand this is just a notational shorthand and not a full-fledged identity. You should now be able to see why the correct identity is
$$y'(t_0) = f(t_0,y_0),$$
and not
$$y'(t_0) = -f(t_0,y_0).$$

**4,5)** I believe my previous answers address these points as well. In particular, there is no "algebra of differentials", only formal differential identities which *mock* specific theorems, and as such they should be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the exhaustive answer. Let me answer by points, to keep simple.
0. I agree, Leibniz notation does not help, I have seen the ambiguity you mention in journal papers and could not understand what they were doing. I in fact don't think that this is really the point that is messing up with me. I kept playing around and I realised that I am messing up with total derivatives, partial derivatives, and lavishly abusing Leibniz notation.

Comment: 1. I reached your result when I realised that I was making a mess between total and partial derivatives. A total derivative would be null because I would be moving *along* the flow of the dynamical system, while a *partial* derivative would let me *change* flow, and so $y_t$. This made me understand why in some situations I was having contrasting results.

Comment: 2. Here is another point where I solved by distinguishing more rigorously between total and partial derivative. I keep in mind that $y'(u)\neq \frac{dy}{du}$, and I look for the latter. If I consider it total, and $y(t)$ written as a function of $y(u)$ via an integral similar to point 1, then things start making completely sense, and indeed $\frac{dy}{du}=0$. If I consider it partial, then using the same form for $y$ I can see $y(t)$ varying from flow to flow as expected, thus its partial derivative *by a future time* is *not* null. It makes sense, thinking to flows of dynamical systems.

Comment: 3. Here is where I do not follow well your reasoning. I do not formulate any inverse in there, so I cannot explain easily how the thing is connected. However, guess what, the derivative I am computing is actually a partial one. In fact I keep $y_0$ constant. If I wanted a total derivative, instead, I should be changing it accordingly, while keeping $t$ constant because I am computing the derivative in there. So the chain rule I wrote doesn't make any sense.

Comment: 4, 5. Same thing over and over again. I am making a mess with Leibniz notation, while confusing partial and total derivatives, and losing from sight the point of tweaking the solution of a dynamical system.

Comment: FInally, thank you very much for taking your time and outpointing the shortfalls of my notation and approach, much appreciated!